# Proof related to a connected graph of diameter 2

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a connected graph of diameter 2. So if κ(G) represents vertex connectivity and λ(G) represents the edge connectivity, then prove that κ(G) = λ(G) for
such G.

What I have tried: Since the diameter is 2, the maximum distance between two vertices should be 2. So I am considering x and y vertices which are connected to another set of vertices. So there is no direct connection between x and y making the diameter 2 as the path to reach from x to y is through another vertex from the set of vertices to which both x and y are connected. The diagram for the same is as below:

[image]

Since it's a connected graph and it should have a diameter of 2 therefore the degree of vertices inside the set should be 2 or else the diameter may increase which is not desired. And the degree of any vertices should not be 1 or else the diameter will also increase as shown below:
[image]

So far looks good to me but I am not sure if this is correct. Moreover, I do not know what to do next. Could you please help me to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @bof oh! I think I got it all wrong then

Comment: @bof okay! I'm going through the concept of diameter but I think I am still not able to comprehend it properly

Comment: The distance $d(x,y)$ between two given vertices $x$ and $y$ is the **minimum** length of a path from $x$ to $y$. Tha diameter of a graph $G$ is the **maximum** of $d(x,y)$ over all vertices $x$ and $y$.

Comment: **Example:** $G$ is a cycle graph of length $8$, with vertices $v_0,v_1 ,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5,v_6,v_7$ and edges $v_0v_1,v_1v_2, v_2v_3,v_3v_4,v_4v_5, v_5v_6,v_6v_7,v_7v_0$. The vertices $v_0$ and $v_2$ are connected by a path $v_0v_1v_2$ of length $2$ and also by a path $v_0v_7v_6v_5v_4v_3v_2$ of length $6$; the distance between $v_0$ and $v_2$ is $d(v_0,v_2)=2$, the length of the shorter path. The **diameter** of $G$ is the maximum distance between two vertices, which is $4=d(v_0,v_4)=d(v_1,v_5)=d(v_2,v_6)=d(v_3,v_7)$. The **longest** (simple) paths in $G$ have length $7$.

Comment: @bof Okay thank you I am able to understand it... I think I messed up everything.

Comment: @bof I have edited out the sentence that was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement you are trying to prove is false; the [butterfly graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_graph) is a counterexample, with $\operatorname{diam}(G)=2$, $\kappa(G)=1$, $\lambda(G)=2$. The question you linked to is about graphs satisfying a different condition, namely, graphs with maximum degree $\Delta(G)\le3$.